# Animating a UIView to slide down, then slide up

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, slider

Im trying to figure out why this isnt working

in my tableViewcontroller viewDidLoad

```
self.headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 320,0)];

self.headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 320, 0)];

self.headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

self.headerLabel.text = @"text";

[self.view addSubview:self.headerView];


[self.headerView addSubview:self.headerLabel];




[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

    self.headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, 320,15);
    self.headerView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 5, 320,15);

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

        self.headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, 320,0);
        self.headerView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 5, 320,0);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

}];
```

if I remove the slide back up part in the completion block of the first animate call It works. The view slides down correctly. However I cannot get it 
to shrink back up at all. When I include the slide up code in the completion block the view is not displayed at all on load and I dont know why and Im going insane

Comment: I tried your code, and I did see the view slide back up, but the label disappeared immediately. Try giving the view a background color, and slow down the animation so you can see it better, and see if you get the same result.

Comment: ok  @rdelmar i added a background color to the view using self.headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; THe code does work.The view comes down, the 2 seconds later goes back up, but the text label disappears immediately after the first animation finishes.

Comment: Yeah, that's just what I saw. Did you also notice that the view comes down over the first cell, rather than pushing the cells down. Do you want it to do that?

Comment: Yes I want it to come down over the cells. I think if I set it as the actual tableHeaderView property of the tableView it would push the cells down.  Why would the text label just disappear like that?? makes no sense @rdelmar

Comment: Actually, animating a header view is kind of complicated, and unless you re-assign the view as the header view during the animation, it doesn't push down the cells.

Comment: @rdelmar im going to try to add the view using my storyboard and see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure why the label disappears, but you can fix that by giving the view and label an appropriate height when you create them, and only animate the label's y position rather than its height.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -30, 320,30)];
    self.headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    self.headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 320, 21)];

    self.headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    self.headerLabel.text = @"text";

    [self.view addSubview:self.headerView];
    [self.headerView addSubview:self.headerLabel];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.headerView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,30);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            self.headerView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, -30, 320,30);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

    }];
}
```

Comment: great idea, dont know why I didnt think of that! ill be sure to try this in the morning thanks

Comment: it works great! exactly what I needed thank you so much. I spent all day yesterday trying to get it to work when the answer was so much easier than what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

viewDidLoad is not really the best place to be starting animations. You should move the code to viewWillAppear: , and if you only want this to occur the first time the view appears, you should add a BOOL property to your controller (i.e. self.hasperformedInitialHeaderAnimation), so:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
if(!self.hasPerformedInitialHeaderAnimation){
self.hasPerformedInitalHeaderAnimation = YES;
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

self.headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, 320,15);
self.headerView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 5, 320,15);

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

    self.headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, 320,0);
    self.headerView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 5, 320,0);

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
}
```

Comment: I tried this. still same result. I put NSLog statements in the animate blocks to see if the code is running. It is, its just the animation that is supposed to slide it back up just removes it completely immediately. No delay. No animation If I remove the animation that slides the view back up it works fine. But if I want to slide it back up it wont work.

Comment: any ideas on why it just disappears?